# how to autodetect location of a user?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My requirement is to auto-detect the location (city, state, and country) of a user logging into a php site. I know there are ways to get the data using the ip address with the help of third party API's like 'ipinfodb'. But these are not accurate and don't show the exact location from where the user has logged in. I think another way is to ask the user to set the location. Also, there seems to be an HTML5 Geolocation API available, but as a matter of fact it seems to be inconsistent or not good enough.

My need is to auto-detect the exact location in some way other than all of the above. Please help me out if there is an answer for this.

Comment: If you can't use IP based solutions or Geolocation, I guess you're screwed, as that's what everyone else is using !

Comment: What other method do you envision? Geolocate API is what's available. If that's not accurate, ask the user.

Comment: Trying the understand the need for accuracy. What are using the location details for?

Comment: 1. Build some hardware dongle with a GPS receiver and make it impossible to login to your site without it. 2. Send this to all of your potential users. 3. ??? 4. Profit!

Comment: And if the user happens to be using a VPN/proxy so their IP appears to be in location X, yet they're halfway around the globe in location Y?

Comment: Maybe the real question is the percentage of precision you want; there's no 100% though (as far as i know), but i would be ok with about 90%+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it.

It's true that the ip is not accurate.

The geolocation API from html5 works thanks to the GPS on mobile devices.

Without those two informations, a computer itself can't detect where it is.

Comment: Thank you for giving a definitive reply.

Answer (score 1):

Auto detection is impossible if you don't want to use the ways you've mentioned. Your best bet is the HTML5 geolocation API, as it is the most accurate (besides asking the user).